# Error in calculation Winforms C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, double

I am building C# WinForms application which has 3 textboxes. First two take value and after calculation show value in third textbox. It has to be in textbox so user can change value if thinks that calculation is wrong. Everything works perfect, but when I run app on windows 7 I get huge error, it calculates that (for example ) 2 times 2.15 is 430. Why is that happening ? I tried installing latest .Net framework on that computer but still doesn't work and after research I have no further ideas.

```
num1 = num2 = sum = 0;
if (tbNum1.Text.Contains(","))
{
    tbNum1.Text = tbNum1.Text.Replace(",", ".");
}

double.TryParse(tbNum1.Text, out num1);
if (tbNum2.Text.Contains(","))
{
    tbNum2.Text = tbNum2.Text.Replace(",", ".");
}

double.TryParse(tbNum2.Text, out num2);
sum = num1 * num2;
sum = Math.Round(sum, 2);
tbSum.Text = sum.ToString();
```

Also, additional two problems appear with displaying WinForm. 
First is that panels have different sizes and positions than I programatically set. 
Secont is that ( and I suppose that is my fault because I am probably doing that wrong ) all panels show very slow. What I have is like 6 panels with particular dimensions and 6 buttons. Depending on pressed button, I set all panels visible to false and only correct panel visible to true. But it loads very slow. Do you have any suggestions ? Thanks a lot in advance !

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem, probably because what is causing the problem is not represented in the code you posted. Tracing through each line of your code in a debugger, will help you zero on to the problem code. You should notice that `2 *  2.15 = 4.3` which is `1/100th` of your obtained answer (something to think about)

Comment: number format generally follows the windows default, so do not use `Replace`, just use your `TryParse` it will fix number 1

Comment: @Vikhram It is not using English number format, if it were it would replace the comma by empty

Comment: Are you sure the culture is set properly on the Windows 7 machine?  I sounds like it is not recognizing the decimal separator in your text boxes.  What, exactly, are you entering there?  Are you entering `2` and `2.15` or `2` and `2,15`  (note the comma in that last entry).

Comment: check the culture of your OS, and exactly what you enter in textboxes

Comment: Posted code is the same but name of variables are changed just to be more readable. I am getting right result on two machines which have OS 10, on one computer with Windows 7 works fine but on another computer with also Windows 7 I get wrong result. 

What is problem ? When I enter value that has comma, I replace it with dot because if I try double.TryParse("2,15",out temp) I get 215 instead 2.15 so I replace comma with dot. Calculating value on 3 computers work fine, but on fourth it calculates that 2 and 2.15 also as 2 and 2,15 is 430.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your parse to a double is wrong. You can do it like this:

```
        double num1, num2, product = 0;

        if (tb1.Text.IndexOf(",") != -1)
        {
            tb1.Text = tb1.Text.Replace(",", ".");
        }
        num1 = double.Parse(tb1.Text, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

        if(tb2.Text.IndexOf(",") != -1)
        {
            tb2.Text = tb2.Text.Replace(",", ".");
        }
        num2 = double.Parse(tb2.Text, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

        product = Math.Round(num1 * num2,2);

        tb3.Text = product.ToString();
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. I tried that, but now on 2,15 and 2 I get 4.62.

Comment: strange, I'm getting the correct result which is 4,3

Comment: Ok, that was my fault because 2.15 times 2.15 is 4.62. 
 num2 = double.Parse(tb1.Text, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

Going to check

Comment: Thanks a lot, it was a problem with culture and in my copy paste. Now I tried it on problematic computer and it works fine ! You are genious :)

Comment: But still there is a problem with displaying panels.
If panel1 has Size(10,10) and location=new Point(10,10)
and second has same size and location = new Point(30,30) on 
3 computers that I tested it would be displayed ok but on problematic one panel2 would be closer to panel1. Why is that so ? And also both panels would be smaller

Comment: good to hear that it's working now! For the panel issue more information would be needed about the purpose of doing it like this. One solution would be to use WPF ;) WinForms is really outdated and not supported anymore

Answer (score 0):

The character that [`double.Parse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.double.parse?view=netframework-4.7.1#System_Double_Parse_System_String_) recognizes as the decimal separator depends on the supplied [`IFormatProvider`](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.iformatprovider?view=netframework-4.7.1); if you don't supply any, that's the one for the current culture.

If you specifically want to use the dot as the decimal separator, you can just use [`CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
double.TryParse(tbNum2.Text, NumberStyles.Any, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out double num);
```